# can't call controller in magento2 2.0.0-rc?

Tags: magento2, module, controllers, custom, magento2-dev-beta

i have custom module.  i can't call controller  in view of my module.
this url call

```
http://localhost/magento2-2.0.0-rc/index.php/namespace/modulename/product/view/custom/
```

Code file **Custom.php** in ***Namespace/Modulename/Controller***

```
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Controller;
class Custom extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * Index action
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('/');
    }
}
```

This file Custom.php in ***Namespace/Modulename/Controller/Product/View***

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Controller\Product\View;


class Custom extends \Namespace\Modulename\Controller\Custom
{

     protected $resultForwardFactory;

    protected $resultPageFactory ;
     protected $_coreRegistry;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, 
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory,      
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry

    ) {
        $this->resultForwardFactory = $resultForwardFactory;
        $this->resultPageFactory  = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }   

    public function execute()
    {   
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        print_r($data); die('xx');
    }
}
```

**Edit**
 routes.xml in etc/frontend

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="modulename" frontName="modulename">
            <module name="Namespace_Modulename" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need declare a route: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/routing.html
....

Comment: yes i have routes.xml in etc/frontend

Answer (score 1):

Clear cache. Magento caches map of controller  actions.

Comment: i made it. but when i run url http://localhost/magento2-2.0.0-rc/index.php/namespace/modulename/product/view/custom/ result 404... So Any suggestion

Comment: check your cache your controller should appear at  *_APP_ACTION_LIST file

Comment: in cache have my controller

Answer (score 1):

once ur module is installed upgrade from cli

```
php D:\xampp\htdocs\magento2a\bin\magento setup:upgrade  (localhost)
```

still you have issue then below are the few file is needed 
1. module.xml
2. app\code\Sugarcode\Test\etc\frontend\routes.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="test" frontName="test">
            <module name="Sugarcode_Test" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

3. action \app\code\Sugarcode\Test\Controller\Index\Index.php

```
<?php
namespace Sugarcode\Test\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
         */
        protected $resultPageFactory;

        /**
         * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
         * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory resultPageFactory
         */
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
        )
        {
            $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
            parent::__construct($context);
        }
    /**
     * Default customer account page
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

4. app\code\Sugarcode\Test\view\frontend\layout\test_index_index.xml

   ```
       <layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../Core/etc/layout_single.xsd">

           <body>
               <referenceContainer name="content">
                   <block  class=""  name="test" template="Sugarcode_Test::index.phtml"></block>
               </referenceContainer>

           </body>
       </layout>
   ```

5.app\code\Sugarcode\Test\view\frontend\templates\index.phtml

```
 <?php
    $message = "Hello World";
    ?>
    <div class= "testclass">
        <?php echo $message;    ?>
    </div>
    <div id="test-re-js" data-mage-init='{"testmodulesjsmap":{"bodySelector": "from phtml file"}}' class="">
    testclass
    </div>
```

url is youdomin.com/test/idex/index

i hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this url instead (remove the namespace part)

http://localhost/magento2-2.0.0-rc/index.php/modulename/product/view/custom/